# How to get last midday in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get the last midday (or last 10am, or last 5pm, etc) from a particular date.

For example:

- `2020-01-19T14:00:00` should return `2020-01-19T12:00:00`

But

- `2020-01-19T09:00:00` should return `2020-01-18T12:00:00`

I know I can find if the hour is bigger than `12` and then simply do `.set(12, 'h')` or if it's smaller, then do `.subtract(1, 'd').set(12, 'h')`, but I'm looking for something already in moment, if it exists.

Is there any method like: `moment().getLast(12, 'd')` (returning the last date that has `day=12`)?

Comment: Why don't you search the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)? FYI, I don't see anything built into moment that does this (at a glance)

Comment: I did. That's why I asked here. If I have found on the docs, I wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: There are many ways to do the same thing in programming. I'm sure you know it. Maybe there is another way I couldn't think about, using the methods available in the docs, that someone used before.